# Wrapimage inside list

Tags: wrapfigure, insbox

My code are as follows:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \input{insbox}
    \makeatletter
    \@InsertBoxMargin = 12pt
    \makeatother
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcommand*{\wrapitem}{\apptocmd{\labelenumi}{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}\item\apptocmd{\labelenumi}{\hskip-\leftmargin}{}{}}
    %
    \newcommand{\InsertListL}[3][]{%
    \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \InsertBoxL{#2}{#3}[#1]\par \hspace{\itemindent}
    }%
    \newcommand{\InsertListR}[3][]{%
    \mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
    \InsertBoxR{#2}{\hskip-\leftmargin#3\hskip\leftmargin}[#1]
    }%

    \begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}%

    \wrapitem%
    \InsertListL[2]{2}{\includegraphics{./images/c01uf006.pdf}}%
    \lipsum[1]

     \item
    \InsertListR[12]{-40}{\includegraphics{./images/c01uf007.pdf}}
    \lipsum[2]

    \wrapitem%
    \InsertListL[2]{2}{\includegraphics{./images/c01uf006.pdf}}%
    \lipsum[1]

    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

Please suggest the below:

1. How can I move the wrap images vertically (upper and down movement)?
2. How can I control unnecessary vertical white spaces?

Also, please correct any errors in coding.

Comment: Please provide a MWE which we can actually use. No one has access to your images except you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose `\includegraphics` in a `\parbox`, that works better, imho. Also use `\wrapitem` only once in one `enumerate` environment (at least in this case this works better). You can control vertical offset with the first mandatory argument of `\InsertList<R/L>` which controls how many lines are typeset normally before the box is inserted (don't use too many here). The optional argument can manipulate the white space around the inserted box.

With this I get the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\input{insbox}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\@InsertBoxMargin = 12pt
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\wrapitem}
  {%
    \apptocmd{\labelenumi}{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}%
    \item
    \apptocmd{\labelenumi}{\hskip-\leftmargin}{}{}%
  }

\newcommand{\InsertListL}[3][]
  {%
    \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}\mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \InsertBoxL{#2}{#3}[#1]\par \hspace{\itemindent}% this \hspace doesn't do anything does it?
  }%
\newcommand{\InsertListR}[3][]
  {%
    \mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
    \InsertBoxR{#2}{\hskip-\leftmargin#3\hskip\leftmargin}[#1]%
  }%

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}%
  \wrapitem%
    \InsertListL[2]{3}{%
      \parbox{8em}{\includegraphics[width=8em]{example-image-a}}}%
    \lipsum[1]
  \item
    \InsertListR[2]{1}{%
      \parbox{8em}{\includegraphics[width=8em]{example-image-b}}}
    \lipsum[2]
  \item%
    \InsertListL[2]{3}{%
      \parbox{8em}{\includegraphics[width=8em]{example-image-c}}}%
    \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great...your suggestion solved the issue....

Comment: @Skillmon: More precisely, the optional argument sets the number of supplementary shorter lines in case TeX doesn't calculate the correct number of shorter lines.

Comment: @Bernard yes. (which is to short, so here is some more text)