# Wrapping figure inside item in enumerate package

Tags: enumerate, wrapfigure

I have got several cases in my article with a brief description of each. I would like to add a drawing wrapped with text.

To highlight my cases I use *enumerate* package.

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Case 1 \\
    A brief discription of case one.
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{Case_1.png}
        \caption{Fig1:Case_1}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \end{enumerate}
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: There is, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419271/wrapimage-inside-list/419275#419275 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59101/will-it-ever-be-possible-to-use-wrapfig-with-an-enumerate-or-itemize-environment